# How to fix SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

my code works fine on other browsers but on Internet Explorer 11 I get *SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference*. Does anyone know how to fix that bug? Here is my code:

```js
var selected

function dragOver(e) {
  if (isBefore(selected, e.target)) e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(selected, e.target)
  else e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(selected, e.target.nextSibling)
}

function dragEnd() {
  selected = null
}

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move"
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", null)
  selected = e.target
}

function isBefore(el1, el2) {
  var cur;
  if (el2.parentNode === el1.parentNode) {
    for (cur = el1.previousSibling; cur; cur = cur.previousSibling) {
      if (cur === el2) return true
    }
  } else return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="sequence">
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="3">Yellow</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="5">Red</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="2">Green</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="1">Blue</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="4">Orange</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverlow ... why don't you add breakpoints and see what's going on? your question does not give us much to go on... `parentNode of undefined` means that the element that you assume exists and has a `parentNode` property, does not... so see what you actually have...

Comment: How did you bind events? What function does the error occur in?

Comment: `selected` is undefined to start with. You call `isBefore` with `selected` and `e.target`, so `el1` is undefined in `isBefore`.

Comment: In which function the error occurs? In `isBefore` or in `dragOver`? If the former, please check the value of `selected` before calling `isBefore`.

Comment: In isBefore function.

Comment: It looks like it's possible, that `dragOver` is called outside of `dragStart`, maybe you should add the listener to the element inside `dragStart`, and remove it in `dragEnd` function ..? Please show the related code, including the HTML, so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! I add my HTML code.

Comment: You're running your code in downgraded document mode. Add a HTML5 document type declaration to your file(s), and if you've included a `http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"` meta tag, make sure its content value is "edge", and the tag is placed within head section, and before any link and script element. After all these, you will have a problem with `e.dataTransfer.setData` method, IE has a bit different argument for the method, I'll try to find the correct arguments ...

Comment: I have <!DOCTYPE html> on start of my HTML and also http-equiv meta tag and content is ie=edge right after my title tag and before all of my scripts. I'm sorry guys if I'm incomprehensible, this is my first question on SO.

Comment: That's an odd error message then. I copied the code on a local file, and it breaks yet in `dragStart`, complaining about `setData` argument being not valid.

Comment: What you think, where is a problem then? It works in my Chrome, without any console error message.

Comment: IE itself is the problem. And Microsoft documentetation policy is another problem. There's not much left from the legacy documentation of IE, and even that small bit is hidden somewhere in the depth of MS archives, and is impossible to find ...

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thank you anyway for your answers and your time, I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and the error occurred firstly in `e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", null)` with argument being not valid. There're two errors in this line：

1. IE only accepts `text` and `URL` as valid data types. You could refer to [this article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/144828/the-html5-drag-and-drop-api/) for explanation:

   > Even though Internet Explorer started out by introducing only "text" and "URL" as valid data types, HTML5 extends this to allow any MIME type to be specified. The values "text" and "URL" will be supported by HTML5 for backwards compatibility, but they are mapped to "text/plain" and "text/uri-list".
2. We should use a concrete value as data instead of `null` in IE. We can use the event target's id for the data.

So this line should be changed into: `e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id)`.

After this, we need to change `ondragover` events to `ondragenter` as I find that `ondragover` won't be fired in IE. So the final code should be like below which can work well in IE 11:

```
var selected

function dragOver(e) {
  if (isBefore(selected, e.target)) e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(selected, e.target)
  else e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(selected, e.target.nextSibling)
}

function dragEnd() {
  selected = null
}

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move"
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id)
  selected = e.target
}

function isBefore(el1, el2) {
  var cur;
  if (el2.parentNode === el1.parentNode) {
    for (cur = el1.previousSibling; cur; cur = cur.previousSibling) {
      if (cur === el2) return true
    }
  } else return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="sequence">
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragenter="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="3">Yellow</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragenter="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="5">Red</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragenter="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="2">Green</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragenter="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="1">Blue</div>
  <div draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd()" ondragenter="dragOver(event)" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="choice 2" id="4">Orange</div>
</div>
```

[Online demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC2UM32RADNJ)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your event handlers:

```js
function dragOver( e ) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
  if ( isBefore( selected, e.target ) ) e.target.parentNode.insertBefore( selected, e.target )
  else e.target.parentNode.insertBefore( selected, e.target.nextSibling )
}
```

Reference:
https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_03.htm (19.3.2. The IE Event Object as a Global Variable)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. I am also getting *SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.* for e.dataTransfer.setData( "text/plain", null )

Comment: You also have to add it in dragStart e.g.:
function dragStart( e ) {
   if (!e) e = window.event;
...

Comment: Yes, I added that in dragStart when I try that but without success.